# Upload a file, from an URL to Google Storage, in a cloud function

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-functions

I try to find a way to upload a PDF file, generated by a php/MySQL server to my Google Storage bucket. The URL is simple : www.my_domain.com/file.pdf . I tried with the code below , but I'm having some issues to make it work. The error is : path (fs.createWriteStream(destination)) must be a string or Buffer. Thanks in advance for your help !

```
const http = require('http');
const fs = require('fs');
const {Storage} = require('@google-cloud/storage')
const gcs = new Storage({
    keyFilename: 'my_keyfile.json'
})
const bucket = gcs.bucket('my_bucket.appspot.com');
const destination = bucket.file('file.pdf');
var theURL = 'https://www.my_domain.com/file.pdf';

var download = function() {

    var file = fs.createWriteStream(destination);
    var request = http.get(theURL, function(response) {
        response.pipe(file);

        file.on('finish', function() {
            console.log("File uploaded to Storage")
            file.close();
        });
    });

}
```

Comment: May you provide more info about what is happening? What errors are you getting? Regards.

Comment: Yes , sorry, I was editing the question. The error is : The error is : path must be a string or Buffer. I can't find a way to target my bucket.

Answer (score 3):

I finally found a solution :

```
const http = require('http');
const fs = require('fs');
const {Storage} = require('@google-cloud/storage')
const gcs = new Storage({
    keyFilename: 'my_keyfile.json'
})
const bucket = gcs.bucket('my_bucket.appspot.com');

const destination = os.tmpdir() + "/file.pdf";
const destinationStorage = path.join(os.tmpdir(), "file.pdf");

var theURL = 'https://www.my_domain.com/file.pdf';

var download = function () {

    var request = http.get(theURL, function (response) {
        if (response.statusCode === 200) {
            var file = fs.createWriteStream(destination);
            response.pipe(file);
            file.on('finish', function () {

                console.log('Pipe OK');

                bucket.upload(destinationStorage, {
                    destination: "file.pdf"
                }, (err, file) => {

                    console.log('File OK on Storage');
                });
                file.close();
            });
        }
    });

}
```

Comment: But, It will be better if we upload the file directly without store into local drive

Answer (score 3):

firebase-admin, as of v7.0.0, uses `google-cloud/storage v2.3.0`, which [can no longer accept file URLs](https://github.com/googleapis/nodejs-storage/releases/tag/v2.0.0) on `bucket.upload`.

I figured I would share my solution as well.

```js
const rq = require('request');

// filePath = File location on google storage bucket
// fileUrl = URL of the remote file

const bucketFile = bucket.file(filePath);
const fileWriteStream = bucketFile.createWriteStream();
let rqPipe = rq(fileUrl).pipe(fileWriteStream);

// And if you want the file to be publicly readable
rqPipe.on('finish', async () => {
  await bucketFile.makePublic();
});
```