# Not uploading file completely on bucket of Google Cloud Storage directly from URL through pipe

Tags: node.js, pipe, google-cloud-storage, firebase-storage

I'm trying to upload file on google firebase storage direct from url. I have review many ways and at the end, used the following solution:

```
const bucket = storage.bucket(bucketName);
const file = bucket.file(destPath + fileName);
return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  try {
    https.get(url, data => {
      if (data && data.statusCode === 200) {
        data.pipe(file.createWriteStream());
        data.on("error", error => {
          reject(error);
        });
        data.on("end", () => {
          resolve(fileName);
        });
      } else {
        const err = new Error(data.statusMessage);
        err.code = data.statusCode;
        data.removeAllListeners();
        reject(err);
      }
      data.on("close", () => {
        console.log("connection closed");
      });
    });
  } catch (err) {
    reject(err);
  }
});
```

It's working fine for many files (image, video, music, document) but getting issue in one video file which showing uploaded successfully on bucket but it's not uploaded completely (uploaded a corrupted file). Also not getting any issue regarding the same. How can I sure that all my files will upload completely. May be there are many corrupted files which are not uploaded completely.

Is there any other way to upload directly to bucket? Please help for the same.

Comment: Have you tried with write stream event data.pipe(file.createWriteStream()).on('finish', ()=> resolve(filename)) instead of data.on('end', ()=>{})

Comment: Thanks for suggestion. Trying to check all cases with your suggested changes, But I want to know what's the difference between these listeners as same files uploaded in different sizes by old one (150 mb, 215 mb and once complete 410 mb). Will this works in all cases?

Comment: You are resolving the promise when read file completes, but write operation is still in progress. In case of small files write operation speed matters. Can you please let us know suggested change works or not?

Comment: @RahulPatil: It is also not working. Any other option?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to follow this documentation? [CreateWriteStream](https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/docs/reference/storage/1.6.x/File#createWriteStream). There is an example there on how to upload a file. Additionally, take a look in this other question, it is a bit similar to yours [Upload a file from URL to Storage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54559244/upload-a-file-from-an-url-to-google-storage-in-a-cloud-function) and I think it can be useful.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. They are just downloading the file by pipe and uploading by buffer but I want to direct upload the file in chunks from url to bucket instead of download in chunks and upload after download completion.