# Firebase Storage upload file from URL with the admin SDK

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-storage

So I am getting the URL of an image into a Firebase Function and need to store that image into the Firebase Storage.

I have tried multiple solutions and have checked out the Firebase and Google Cloud docs, but haven't found anything for that problem.

Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: You'll need to download the data from the URL first, after which you can upload it to Cloud Storage. If you've already tried this, show the [minimal code that reproduces where you got stuck](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I get that and I have tried it. My "minimal code that reproduces where you got stuck" is not there, because I have no code that is close to any solution. I am really looking for some help, because I can not think of a way to download the data, save it into a file and the upload it to the storage. Only how to create a stream of the data, but that does not help in this case. If you have any clue, an answer would be greatly appriciated!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54559244/upload-a-file-from-an-url-to-google-storage-in-a-cloud-function and probably more from this list: https://www.google.com/search?q=cloud+functions+upload+to+storage+from+url

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I will try out that solution, but that google search is not that helpful (look at my browser history and you will see that I DID search for quite some time), because almost all questions are about "how to get an URL from an uploaded file".

Comment: Yeah thanks that worked! @FrankvanPuffelen